# Any Way to Run Android App in tablet Like Phone Same As Possible in IOS

Tags: android, ios, ios6

I want to Ask One Question that is More Important For **Android & IOS**.

We see in `IOS` You Can Run `IOS App` (Created By `IOS Phone` only) that app Run in Tablet
Device & work As `Iphone` As shown in Image.

[image]

Is there Any Way to Run `Android` App (Created By `Android Phone` only) that app Run in Tablet Device & work As `Android Phone` As shown in image.

is this Possible in `Android`!

Any help?.

Comment: its possible if we created the app with fragment concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android actually handles this better than iOS, it scales the app up. Any app on the Play store  which isn't being filtered will work on any Android device.

In iOS you have different views for your iPad/iPhone on Android you use `Fragments` to acheive the same result see [Designing for Handset and Tablet](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html).

Personally its better on Android as you can reuse componentized UI.

IF you really want to make it look like a phone app, you can use scaled mode, (if you target your app against gingerbread `targetSdk="10"`) then Honeycomb+ will present the users with scaled mode similar to the iOS thing. I by no means recommend this! It is the worst UX you can give your users!